# Unable to import s3 data to RDS(Postgresql) using aws_commons extension

Tags: postgresql, amazon-s3

I am trying to import s3 file(CSV file) to Postgre sql rds instance.
I am running s3 import queries from rds instance as per AWS docs but i am getting below error

ERROR:  syntax error at or near ":"
LINE 5:    :'s3_uri',
           ^
SQL state: 42601
Character: 76

Query i used for downloading s3 file is below:

SELECT aws_s3.table_import_from_s3(
   't1',
   '', 
   '(format csv)',
   :'s3_uri',
);

Running query as per AWS doc: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/PostgreSQL.Procedural.Importing.html#USER_PostgreSQL.S3Import.Overview

SELECT aws_s3.table_import_from_s3(
   't1',
   '', 
   '(format csv)',
   :'s3_uri',
);

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error. Solved it with these steps:

TLDR: when you're importing data with aws_commons, you want to provide the credentials and path to the s3 asset you're working with rather than a variable that stores that information. So, assuming you've already created an IAM role and policy to allow your database to access s3, then you run

```
SELECT aws_s3.table_import_from_s3('table_name',
'"col1", "col2", "col3"',
'(format csv)',
's3_bucket_name',
'file_name.csv',
'region',
'access_key',
'secret_key');
```

1. upgrade postgres to version 14.4 (though 12.4 [also works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64501490/unable-to-export-aws-rds-postgres-table-to-csv-in-s3-using-aws-s3-query-export))
2. install aws_commons `CREATE EXTENSION aws_s3 CASCADE;`
3. Create IAM role `aws iam create-role --role-name $ROLE_NAME    --assume-role-policy-document '{"Version": "2012-10-17", "Statement": [{"Effect": "Allow", "Principal": {"Service": "rds.amazonaws.com"}, "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"}]}'`
4. Create an IAM policy for the IAM role `aws iam create-policy \ --policy-name $POLICY_NAME \ --policy-document '{"Version": "2012-10-17", "Statement": [{"Sid": "s3import", "Action": ["s3:GetObject", "s3:ListBucket"], "Effect": "Allow", "Resource": ["arn:aws:s3:::${BUCKET_NAME}", "arn:aws:s3:::${BUCKET_NAME}/*"]}]}'`
5. Attach the policy `aws iam attach-role-policy \ --policy-arn arn:aws:iam::$AWS_ACCOUNT_ID:policy/$POLICY_NAME \ --role-name $ROLE_NAME`

*Note:*
*Steps 1 - 5 worked for allowing data exports from postgres, importing from s3 was failing until I added step  6.*

6. Create the VPC endpoint for the S3 service `aws ec2 create-vpc-endpoint \ --vpc-id $VPC_ID \ --service-name com.amazonaws.$REGION.s3 --route-table-ids $ROUTE_TABLE_ID`

*The route table id related to the VPC where the endpoint is created can be retrieved through the command*
`aws ec2 describe-route-tables | jq -r '.RouteTables[] | "\(.VpcId) \(.RouteTableId)"'`

7. run `SELECT aws_s3.table_import_from_s3('table_name','"col1", "col2", "col3"','(format csv)','s3_bucket_name', 'file_name.csv', 'region', 'access_key','secret_key');`

References:

1. [Importing data from Amazon S3 into an RDS for PostgreSQL DB instance](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_PostgreSQL.S3Import.html#USER_PostgreSQL.S3Import.FileFormats)
2. [Examples of importing data from Amazon S3 into an RDS for PostgreSQL DB instance](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_PostgreSQL.S3Import.html#USER_PostgreSQL.S3Import.FileFormats)
3. [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58616005/import-postgres-data-into-rds-using-s3-and-aws-s3)

Answer (score 0):

`:'` is not a valid syntax.  `:'s3_uri'`, including the leading colon, need to be replaced with a s3 URI.  When you are done, there should be no literal colon there outside the quotes.

Comment: S3 URI Query: SELECT aws_commons.create_s3_uri(
   'test-postgress3',
   'rds.csv',
   'us-east-1'
) AS s3_uri
        
AND
Query i used to download S3 file : SELECT aws_s3.table_import_from_s3(
   't1',
   '', 
   '(format csv)',
   :"s3_uri",
);


I tried Multiple ways of adjusting S3_uri but nothing seems to be working
And i completely didn't understand your answer. Could you please edit my query or provide me new query ?

Answer (score -3):

Try add \n before :

```sql
SELECT aws_s3.table_import_from_s3( 't1', '', '(format csv)', 
:'s3_uri', );
```

Comment: Can you provide more info here, how will adding a newline help?