# Permission denied when trying to load into Postgres RDS from S3 with a path that contains the equals sign

Tags: postgresql, amazon-s3, amazon-rds

I'm trying to load data into Postgres RDS from S3 using the method `aws_s3.table_import_from_s3` as explained here: [Importing Data into PostgreSQL on Amazon RDS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/PostgreSQL.Procedural.Importing.html)

The file path in S3 contains the equals sign '=' and because of it I'm getting the following error:

```
ERROR:  HTTP 403. Permission denied. Check bucket or provided credentials as they may no longer be valid.
```

When replacing the equals sign with another character like underscore '_', the import succeeds.

Example:

```sql
SELECT aws_s3.table_import_from_s3(
     'my_table',
     'col1,col2',
     '(format csv)',
     'my_bucket',
     'date=20191031/my_data.csv',
     'eu-west-2'
);
```

Throws the error mentioned above. (HTTP 403...)

While:

```sql
SELECT aws_s3.table_import_from_s3(
     'my_table',
     'col1,col2',
     '(format csv)',
     'my_bucket',
     'date_20191031/my_data.csv',
     'eu-west-2'
);
```

Succeeds without any problem

Is there any escape char I should add to the equals sign? Any other solution?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I didn't test it, but should work. Just encode `=` with `%3D`.

```
SELECT aws_s3.table_import_from_s3(
 'my_table',
 'col1,col2',
 '(format csv)',
 'my_bucket',
 'date%3D20191031/my_data.csv',
 'eu-west-2');
```

Comment: @dvainrub glad to know it worked. Would you mind accepting this as correct answer? It will help others. Community contribution you know ;)

Answer (score 5):

I also faced this issue of `Permission denied. Check bucket or provided credentials as they may no longer be valid` when using the function `aws_s3.table_import_from_s3`.

First tried to URL encode the whole path but that also encodes the `/` slashes which interferes with the S3 object path separator.  Hereby just URL encode everything except the slashes.

**PHP example to URL encode**

```php
$path = implode('/', array_map('urlencode', explode('/', $path)));
```

**Before - not working**

```sql
SELECT aws_s3.table_import_from_s3(
   'TABLE_NAME',
   '',
   '(FORMAT csv, HEADER true)',
   aws_commons.create_s3_uri('BUCKET', 'subdirectory/2020-09-10T09:48:40.831Z-6402c3e6-86e6-4a15-8bc3-51d9eb9f08a3.csv', 'aws-region'),
   aws_commons.create_aws_credentials('***', '***', '')
)
```

**After - working**

```sql
SELECT aws_s3.table_import_from_s3(
   'TABLE_NAME',
   '',
   '(FORMAT csv, HEADER true)',
   aws_commons.create_s3_uri('BUCKET', 'subdirectory/2020-09-10T09%3A48%3A40.831Z-6402c3e6-86e6-4a15-8bc3-51d9eb9f08a3.csv', 'aws-region'),
   aws_commons.create_aws_credentials('***', '***', '')
)
```

Ideally this would be handled by the function `aws_commons.create_s3_uri` provided with `aws_s3` extension.

Comment: i tried this, and still got a 403. I think it's because I'm trying to use a timestamp (with :, which "might require special handling" https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingMetadata.html#object-key-guidelines) in a folder name. I think this extension hasn't received much love. I'm changing to epoch time

Comment: The import extension functionality between AWS RDS Postgres 12.x and 12.4-R1 did change: in the 12.4-R1 version you do not need to encode it anymore; importing from sub-directories seems to fail, hereby you need to switch to the root of the bucket (in my case I switched to a new bucket). More info here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64387564/5731721