# How to choose an aws rds with postgres engine that supports s3Export and s3Import?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I need to use the aws_s3 plugin to export/import files from AWS RDS.
I thought this was going to be simple but for some reason the aws_s3.quert_export_to_s3 does not work.

Here are functions available in the RDS:

[image: Functions present in my was rds postgres]

I read that it may be an issue with the postgres version.
So I ran `aws rds describe-db-engine-versions > temp.json` to check which version supported s3Import/s3Export.

The output had me confused since the same postgres version was listed multiple times with different features.

One said:

```json
{
"Engine": "postgres",
"EngineVersion": "11.1",
"DBParameterGroupFamily": "postgres11",
"DBEngineDescription": "PostgreSQL",
"DBEngineVersionDescription": "PostgreSQL 11.1-R1",
"ValidUpgradeTarget": [
  {
  "Engine": "postgres",
  "EngineVersion": "12.5",
  "Description": "PostgreSQL 12.5-R1",
  "AutoUpgrade": false,
  "IsMajorVersionUpgrade": true
  }
],
"SupportedFeatureNames": [
    "s3Import"
  ]
}
```

While another said:

```json
{
"Engine": "postgres",
"EngineVersion": "10.15",
"DBParameterGroupFamily": "postgres10",
"DBEngineDescription": "PostgreSQL",
"DBEngineVersionDescription": "PostgreSQL 10.15-R1",
"ValidUpgradeTarget": [
  {
  "Engine": "postgres",
  "EngineVersion": "12.5",
  "Description": "PostgreSQL 12.5-R1",
  "AutoUpgrade": false,
  "IsMajorVersionUpgrade": true
  },
],
"SupportedFeatureNames": [
    "s3Import",

  ]
}
```

In the AWS portal I only get to select the version as `12.5-R1` or `13.1-R1` but not between these subversion.

I want to use a version which supports both export&import. How do I do that?

Comment: Might be helpful: [postgresql - Unable to export AWS RDS Postgres table to CSV in S3, using aws_s3.query_export_to_s3 function - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64501490/unable-to-export-aws-rds-postgres-table-to-csv-in-s3-using-aws-s3-query-export)

Comment: I went through that answer. The soln was to use Postgres 12.4, but right now AWS RDS does not have that version.

Comment: Can you please edit your Question to show the commands you were trying to use, and the error that you received, so we can try to reproduce? Also FYI: [postgresql - Import Postgres data into RDS using S3 and aws_s3 - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58616005/import-postgres-data-into-rds-using-s3-and-aws-s3)

Answer (score 0):

as per AWS [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/postgresql-s3-export.html#postgresql-s3-supported)  `Currently, Amazon S3 exports are supported for PostgreSQL 10.14, 11.9, and 12.4 and later.`

you can use the below snippet to validate if your version supports exports/imports

```
aws rds describe-db-engine-versions --region us-east-1 --engine postgres --engine-version <your version> | grep s3Export
```

If the output includes the string "s3Export", then the engine supports Amazon S3 exports. Otherwise, the engine doesn't support them.

and in case if you have recently upgraded from lower versions, then you have to update all extensions, try this solved my issue

```
DROP EXTENSION aws_s3 CASCADE;
DROP EXTENSION aws_commons CASCADE;
CREATE EXTENSION aws_s3 CASCADE;
```

Comment: Hey @Nikhil, this does not solve my problem. The `query_export_to_s3` function still doesn't accept the secret key and access key

Comment: can you share which command are you using @asds_asds